# Generics in typedef functions

Tags: generics, dart

I'm writing a tree utility and need to be able to pass some anonymous functions. I like to have things strongly typed where possible, and I know this can be achieved by using dynamics.

The typedef I want to create will return the models key, and parentKey so that the tree handler can generate a tree out of a flat collection.

This is the pseudo code I have:

```
typedef KeySelector<T> = dynamic Function<T>(T item);


/// The handler for tree structures
class TreeHandler<T> {
  /// The items in a flattened structure
  final List<T> items;

  /// Selector function for an items key
  final KeySelector<T> keySelector;

  /// Selector function for an items parent key
  final KeySelector<T> parentKeySelector;

  /// The actual tree the items
  /// are converted into
  List<TreeNode<T>> tree;

  TreeHandler(this.items, this.keySelector, this.parentKeySelector);
}
```

And the class consuming this utility has this initialisation code:

```
class MyModel {
  MyModel({this.id, this.parentId});

  int id;
  int parentId;
}

_treeHandler = TreeHandler<MyModel>(
      null,
      <MyModel>(MyModel m) => m.id,
      <MyModel>(MyModel m) => m.parentId,
    );
```

Here I get errors saying "[dart] the getter id isn't defined for the class Object".

I have tried different kind of ways to initialise the TreeHandler correctly but just can't seem to get it right.

For instance, this initialisation works, but is not strongly typed anymore:

```
_treeHandler = TreeHandler<MyModel>(
   null,
   <MyModel>(dynamic m) => m.id,
   <MyModel>(dynamic m) => m.parentId,
);
```

I might be abusing the framework, but I really do hope its possible to achieve this by using generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
typedef KeySelector<T> = dynamic Function(T item);

class TreeNode<T> {}

/// The handler for tree structures
class TreeHandler<T> {
  /// The items in a flattened structure
  final List<T> items;

  /// Selector function for an items key
  final KeySelector<T> keySelector;

  /// Selector function for an items parent key
  final KeySelector<T> parentKeySelector;

  /// The actual tree the items
  /// are converted into
  List<TreeNode<T>> tree;

  TreeHandler(this.items, this.keySelector, this.parentKeySelector);
}

class MyModel {
  MyModel({this.id, this.parentId});

  int id;
  int parentId;
}

void main() {
  var _treeHandler = TreeHandler<MyModel>(
    null,
    (MyModel m) => m.id,
    (MyModel m) => m.parentId,
  );
}
```

I think the main problem is that you have 2 generic parameters with the same name where one hides the other

```
typedef KeySelector<T> = dynamic Function<T>(T item);
```

This is a generic typedef for a generic function where `KeySelector<T>` introduces a generic parameter `T` for the typedef and `Function<T>` introduces a generic parameter `T` for the generic function.

Changing it to

```
typedef KeySelector<T> = dynamic Function(T item);
```

resolves this.

Comment: Thanks Gunter, that change certainly did the trick. Can't believe I didn't try that.. Thanks for the quick response.